# android onClick for imageview not fired

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a common layout which I use in all my activities. In the title layout, I have an imageview included and there is an onclick method specified in the xml layout for this imageview.

In one of my activities, the onclick for this imageview is not fired in the java code. Following is the layout of the activity I refer to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit_createprofile"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:onClick="onCreateExitClick"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/exit_createprofile"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:onClick="onCreateSaveClick"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="40dp" >

    <br.com.dina.ui.widget.UITableView
        android:id="@+id/profileList_create"
        style="@style/UITableView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

and the layout specified in include is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/list_item_top"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@color/background_grey"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBack"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:onClick="onBackClick"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_back" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textSize="18sp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

I have even tried, using the following code in the activity, but still, the onclick is not fired:

```
backImage = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
    backImage.setClickable(true); 
    backImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title back clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
```

I am left with no clues as to why this onclick is not getting fired. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my screen:

[image]

Comment: _In one of my activities, the onclick for this imageview is not fired_ --- does that mean it is working on some other activities?

Comment: yes, it works in other

Comment: That says the issue is most probably with that particular "activity". Are there any difference in what it `extends` or `implements` than the others?

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:clickable="true"` in your `ImageView` inside XML layout.

OR

```
backImage.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: @user1400538 remove focusable from ImageView layout.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
backImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
backImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title back clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
```

Comment: @PareshMayani : Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @user1400538 His question is "Why are you using `getApplicationContext()` in your `Toast`?"

Answer (score 1):

If your imageview is in included layout than try this

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.includeTitle);
```

And then

```
backImage = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
```

Comment: @user1400538 Remove `android:onClick="onBackClick"` attribute in your xml or Take a `onBackClick(View v)` method in your Activity

Comment: @user1400538 YOu haven't removed this `android:onClick="onBackClick"` this attribute in your xml for `Imageview`

Comment: i did this and checked, but no luck